# R: How to make replicate() and sapply() produce the same result?

Tags: r

I simulate with `replicate()` the distribution of the mean of ten numbers by repeating the operation five times.

```
> set.seed(123)
> z <- replicate(5, mean(rnorm(10))
```

I would like to create with `sapply` a second vector `q` such that

```
> identical(z, q)
[1] TRUE
```

Despite of the rich documentation in [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) and in the `help` files, I fail to produce a code with `sapply` capable of integrate the five-times repetition that produced `z`.
Indeed, the best result I got includes `replicates()` itself:

```
set.seed(123)
q <- sapply(replicate(5, rnorm(10)), mean)
```

and it produces a vector `q` of length 50, instead of a vector of length 5 as in `z`. I am afraid it is an *egg of Columbus* that I am looking from the wrong perspective.

Comment: you want:
`sapply(1:5, function(x) mean(rnorm(10)))` In this case, `replicate` will be a better choice

Comment: `apply(t(replicate(5, rnorm(10))), 1, mean)`

Comment: Thank you @Jeremycg, it works. If I got the meaning of your function, it is equivalent to `sapply(1:5, function(x) {mean(rnorm(10))})`. May I ask why `replicate` is a better choice here?